# How to delete the session file when disconnecting?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

My `session` management is `file` based :

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = RP_MAIN . 'sessions/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

When the app disconnects then I want the session file to be deleted :

```
public function logout()
{
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('/login/index');
}
```

Attention should be considered about the many users connecting to the app : there may be many clients using the app if the app is inside an application server.

So how to delete the session file according to a particular user ?

Comment: what do you mean with "disconnect" ?

Comment: $this->session->sess_destroy(); function will destroy session of that particular user only ( the user who has session and execute this url/function ). Sessions are based on session_id which temp get stored in browser.

Comment: by "disconnect" I mean loggin off from the app.